how to get the location from windows using python
I want to get the location from windows
I tried to get the loc from IP using ipinfo.io but the info is vaild so i want to take the loc from windows
I just want how to get tje location
I didn't found any thing on the internet

What do you mean by "the location from Windows"? Do you mean you are trying to get the geographical location of a Windows computer? What location are you after - the location that the Windows machine is configured to assume it is in, or the closest known geographical location for the current internet IP (which may be very far away, especially when using a VPN)

I've had a quick look around, but it appears there is no straightforward answer. There are ways to access the Windows Location API, but on many computers (my own included) Windows isn't allowed to get location information, and accessing the API will result in errors. You could write code that uses the API if available, and fall back on online services like ipinfo.io. If you ask any AI chatbot how to access the Location API with something like pywin32 you should have little trouble, provided Location services are enabled on the computer.

This works for me
import requests

def get_global_ip():
    try:
        response = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json')
        data = response.json()
        return data['ip'], data['country'], data['city']
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error while retrieving location:", e)
        return None

global_ip = get_global_ip()
if global_ip:
    print("Your global IP address and location:", global_ip)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the global IP address and location")

or if you know your ip you can try this:
import requests

def get_location(ip):
    url = f"http://ip-api.com/json/{ip}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    if data['status'] == 'success':
        return data['city'], data['country']
    else:
        return None

my_ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' # global/white ip-address

location = get_location(my_ip)
if location:
    city, country = location
    print(f"Your city: {city}, country: {country}")
else:
    print("It is not possible to get info about your location :(")



If you want to use the IP2Location.io free API, the below code will work for your public IP address.
import requests

def get_my_public_ip():
    try:
        response = requests.get('https://api.ip2location.io/')
        data = response.json()
        return data['ip'], data['country_code'], data['country_name'], data['region_name'], data['city_name'], data['latitude'], data['longitude'], data['zip_code'], data['time_zone'], data['asn'], data['as'], data['is_proxy']
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error while retrieving location:", e)
        return None

my_public_ip = get_my_public_ip()
if my_public_ip:
    print("Your public IP address and location:", my_public_ip)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the public IP address and location")

